# Cocoa : How to make a small toolbar like in Pages or Numbers?

Tags: cocoa, xcode

Apples Application like Pages and Numbers always show an additional small Toolbar under the main Toolbar. Is there an object like this in the Interface Builder or do I have to build it from scratch?
I looked in the IB Library but found nothing so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no build-in control for that. You can take a look at the [BWToolkit](http://brandonwalkin.com/bwtoolkit/) from Brandon Walkin. It has a lot of nice controls to build Apple-like applications. Maybe it can fit your needs...

Answer (score 3):

You use NSSegmentedControl objects to do that, styled to Capsule. To achieve segmented controls with labels aligned underneath (which are clickable, like in Mail.app and Preview.app), you need to put them into toolbar button groups. That can't be done in IB. See this discussion in the Cocoa mailing list:

http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/204390-capsule-style-toolbar-controls.html

Answer (score 1):

It's just a simple view containing various controls. You could build most of it directly in Interface Builder. Just create an NSBox, give it a background color and then place "Mini"-sized controls in it.